# postgresql-13-postgis-3 : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, postgresql-13, postgis-installation

I am trying to install the `postgresql-13-postgis-3` package using following method on ubuntu `18.04` version. I have tried following method,

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo wget --no-check-certificate --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update -y; sudo apt install -y postgresql-13 postgresql-13-postgis-3 postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13
```

But I am getting following error,

```
postgresql-client-13 is already the newest version (13.5-1.pgdg18.04+1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-13-postgis-3 : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone suggest to me, how to install the postGIS in ubuntu 18.04? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 18.04 or 20.04? your question mentions both

Comment: Even if this is off-topic here: why do you try to install packages from 18.04 on 20.04?

Comment: Sorry, I mean 18.04. I corrected the question.

Comment: Please add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/`

Answer (score 1):

The missing dependency is available in `universe`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgdal20
```

Comment: I already installed the `GDAL 3.0.1` and I have some other dependencies on it. So I can't install the `libgdal20`. It shows me the dependency error.

Comment: @gis please update the question to know the missing dependencies.